# sent btc to bcc address. what can i do to stop swearing?

Tags: transactions, wallet, address, bitcoin-cash, breadwallet

Both are my accounts. Two hours ago i sent 0.2 btc from breadwallet to wirex in orden to add funds to my debit card. But I mixed up addresses and they went to a bcc one. I wrote to both supports, with no answer yet. I did not know a thing about replay protection. Is it by default or should I do something to get my transaction rejected. I don't even know if it's anything I could do, in fact.

Comment: You made a transaction on the wrong chain?  Addresses wouldn't really matter if you have the keys.

Comment: nope, you don't control your private keys with wirex :/ 
it would be so much easier

i got an answer from breadwallet explaining it's not lost, it's just on the btc chain, same address. I should provide the transaction ID and wait for wirex to kindly recognize my btc, breadwallet said

I share this if somebody else do the same stupid thing, because there is nothing online yet

If somebody else have a better idea or know about another debit card with a 2000 limit with no verification...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/57596/54178) to know what happens if you send BTC to BCC.

As of your case, if you were holding the private keys of both the wallets, then you could simply retrieve it except the transaction fees.

But in your case, you have send the BTC to an unknown BCC address. You cannot tell who owns that address. The person who owns the private key of that address gets the BTC.

If by any chance, that address is of Wirex, then you have a good chance to get that in your account, as if they hold the private key of that address, they have access to both BTC and BCC in that address.

Comment: hey guess what? it took 22 hours to get an answer from wirex. i received one mail saying something like "hi! eugene was assigned to help on this. please be patient while he analizes it". One minute later, the fastest support agent bring the brightest answer "we do not have any information regarding BCC support as of now. we will keep you update through our blog"

- great, so i should just let you alone with my money. why didn't you ask for it earlier hon?

so i provided him all sort of forum threads and a rush class about what i learnt today. your private keys, my tuition fees.