# Bitcoin Cash accidentally sent to Bitcoin address. Can I get them back?

Tags: address, bitcoin-cash, wallet-recovery, cross-chain-recovery

I managed my Bitcoins Cash in a Electrum Cash wallet on my PC. 
From there, I accidentally sent them to another internet based wallet, but didn't notice that this wallet is for Bitcoin and not Bitcoin Cash.
In the Bitcoin Cash blockchain I can see that the transaction actually took place and that the adress now owns the Bitcoin Cash. The problem is, that this address is a Bitcoin Cash address, and I cannot get access to it.

Is there a way to reclaim this Bitcoin Cash address? I own the address on Bitcoin, but not on Bitcoin Cash.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of the reverse situation "BTC sent to BCH address". While https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bch-aka-bcc-add is highly related and informative, there is an asymmetry to this problem, and I don't think the linked question fully answers the question here, so I have decided to remove the duplicate link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case I sent the Bitcoin Cash to an address created by a Mobile Bitcoin (!) wallet from btc.com.

The support from btc.com told me the solution:

> B) You have sent BCC to your BTC wallet:
>   1. Use your BTC recovery PDF at https://bcc-recovery.btc.com/ (click on 'forgot password' to use your backup PDF)
>   2. Recover the coins to an address from your BCC wallet

There was not even the need to click on "forgot password". I just logged in there with my username and password of the mobile Bitcoin (!) wallet and then it started to scan some addresses - and actually found the address I had send the bitcoin cash to. It then allowed me to specify another bitcoin cash adress where to send the money to.

So, I am lucky now, I have back the bitcoin cash the I thought I would never see again

Answer (score 4):

Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash use the same address format. This means that if you take the key from your Bitcoin Core client, and import it to your Bitcoin Cash client, the Bitcoin Cash client will be able to spend that money.

However, if someone else operates the Bitcoin Core client, you need to convince them to send you the money.

Comment: This is only true if the recipient address is not of the segwit format.

Comment: And if it is Segwit?

Comment: @Josh Segwit transactions are anyone-can-spend on the Bitcoin Cash blockchain. However, it's unlikely that someone would accidentally create a segwit transaction on the Bitcoin Cash blockchain.

Comment: Hmm anyone-can-spend?

Comment: @NickODell: Well, the problem isn't that someone would create a segwit transaction, but rather that someone accidentally sent Bitcoin Cash to a wrapped segwit address which looks indistinguishable from any other P2SH address to the sender.