# Did I lose my Bitcoin cash sending from an exchange to a Bitgo bitcoin wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery, bitgo

No transaction is showing up on the blockchain or at Bitgo Bitcoin wallet.

Comment: Which exchange? Did you send Bitcoin or Bitcoin Cash from the exchange? Did you send before or after the fork?

Comment: It was sent after the fork from a Bittrex bitcoin cash wallet to a Bitgo bitcoin wallet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitcoin Cash accidentally sent to Bitcoin address. Can I get them back?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57713/bitcoin-cash-accidentally-sent-to-bitcoin-address-can-i-get-them-back)