# Can I access a BCH wallet with a BTC seed phrase?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash, wallet-recovery, cross-chain-recovery

So I've accidentally given someone a BTC address and she sent BCH to this address. The wallet was created post-fork. Is it possible to go through the same process as accessing BCH immediately after the hard fork, or are these BCH funds lost forever?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57713/bitcoin-cash-accidentally-sent-to-bitcoin-address-can-i-get-them-back

Answer (score 1):

If the seed phrase was generated by a BTC [BIP-0039](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) compliant wallet and you have a BIP-0039 compliant BCH wallet then the answer is yes you should be able to get hold of your BCH funds.

It should be easy to try. Get a BCH wallet and enter your seed phrase and see if your coins appear.