# Mistakenly sent BCH to BTC bitfinex wallet - can I get my BCH back?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery, bitfinex

I just made the huge mistake to sent BCH from Exodus to my BTC wallet in bitfinex. Can I by any chance get my BCH back?

Comment: BCC? BCH and BCC mostly means Bitcoin Cash. Do you mean Bitconnect "BCC"?

Comment: Sorry.. That was stupid.. I have sent Bitcoin Cash from exodus to my Bitcoin wallet in Bitfinex.. @MCCCS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitcoin Cash accidentally sent to Bitcoin address. Can I get them back?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57713/bitcoin-cash-accidentally-sent-to-bitcoin-address-can-i-get-them-back)

Comment: @PieterWuille Probably. But I do not know how to find my private key in Bitfinex. And furthermore, if I find my private key in Bitfinex I will not know how to import it in Exodus? (Yes I am pretty new in this game)

Answer (score 2):

They will be recoverable, but only by the exchange the money was sent to.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am pretty new in this crypto-world, so all help would be much appreciated! @eponymous

Comment: Bitfinex will need to assist you to recover your mis-directed transaction.

Comment: bitfinex expects that you send btc to address xy, because xy is a wallet of bitfinex. so bitfinex has the privatekey of xy. but you sent some bch to xy on the bch-blockchain. the private key of xy is the same on the bch- and on the  btc-blockchain. so bitfinex can (if bitfinex is accommodating) send your bch back to you. (or bitfinex could deposit this bch-value to your bitfinex-bch-wallet.)
they can definitively, but they must not. this depends probably on the effort of a bitfinex-employee

Comment: @KarenMarieSteffensen, please don't use **crypto** to mean cryptocurrencies. *crypto* == **cryptography**, not cryptocurrencies

Answer (score 0):

Its nearly impossible to recover. The BTC address you sent the BCH to is (very much possible) not even owned by anyone.

Comment: actually, you can use the private key from the BTC wallet to create a BCH wallet.  Of course, this only works if you have the private key for the BTC wallet, which the OP clearly *does* have.

Comment: @MaxVernon, it is my wallet but I do not know how to find my private key in Bitfinex? I have found it in Exodus, but that does not help me out does it?

Comment: No, you'd need the key for the bitfinex account.  Contact bitfinex to see if they can help you.