# bch transfered to cashadrrs instead of legacy

Tags: address, coinbase.com, cash

I tried to transfer BCH from Coinbase to Ledger Nano S.The nano ledger S gave me a legacy address starting with a (1)
Coinbase sent it out to a cash addr. How can I get a hold of this BCH. Looking on Blockchair I see my transaction. I see my ledger address starting with a 1 and I see the cash addr. starting with a q. Coinbase tells me I have to sync my wallet with the cash addr. Blockchain.

Can anybody help???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitcoin Cash accidentally sent to Bitcoin address. Can I get them back?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57713/bitcoin-cash-accidentally-sent-to-bitcoin-address-can-i-get-them-back)

Comment: Whta was the transaction id given?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would happen if you send Bitcoin (BTC) to a Bitcoin Cash (BCH, aka BCC) address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bch-aka-bcc-add)

Comment: Please don't flag this question as duplicate. They've sent BCH to their BCH address, but they have problems with the address format.

Answer (score 1):

It should show up in your Ledger.

Cashaddr is a representation of the underlying hash for that address. Each BCH address has a legacy and a cashaddr format. In your case, it is simply likely that the block explorer Coinbase links to defaults to showing the cashaddr format. There are explorers which will show you both, such as [blockchair](https://blockchair.com).

For instance, looking up the address [1FPS2Y71KhNQbugjMxAGKwsUFNbvfsYm2h](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/address/1FPS2Y71KhNQbugjMxAGKwsUFNbvfsYm2h) on blockchair will show you it's cashaddr representation as well, which is `qzwulnvalvs6gwfy9t7gz5qxs22t9fag45tpcgu32g`. Funds sent to either of the above will be accessible by the same private key, in a wallet following either format. Both addresses refer to the same underlying script.