# Sent BCH accidently to Bitcoin address

Tags: bitcoin-cash

i have sent 0.29379525 Bitcoin Cash (BCH) accidentally to my BTC wallet. and i have received nothing. Can you please help me?
here is the transaction id.
102260de41a9088ca0da20257cba0e054c10d1febe0d6b2b3ebb0a42d858d483
I just accidentally my BTC wallet instead of BCH
I sent BCH from my bittrex account to my bitpay account. I just copied BTC address from my bitPay account instead of BCH. and sent funds from my bittrex account to that wallet. how can i recover those funds? Transaction is confirmed from bittrex account. and bittrex support is not ready to help me.

Comment: There are some questions on here about recovering bcash sent to the wrong address, but since you sent it to a Bitpay account (which I assume is a custodial wallet), you will need to contact Bitpay in order to retrieve your funds. If Bitpay is not custodial, then this question has already been answered on here, you can find the answer using the search function.

Comment: How to find if Bitpay wallet is custodial or not?

Comment: You will need to find a way to dump private keys from the Bitpay wallet. If it is custodial, this will not be possible, since Bitpay will control the keys and not make them available to you. If you have a 12 or 24 word seed phrase backup for the wallet, that is a good sign, it means it is non-custodial. You will just need to figure out how to get the private key for the address you sent those funds to. Search on this site for BCH recovery questions, you will find step-by-step instructions on how to proceed recovering your funds.

Comment: I have access to private key of bitpay wallet BTC. to which i sent BCH. so its non-custodial. probblem i have tried importing from btc recovery to btc. but it gives problem :( I can access my private key. but don't know what to do with that to recover funds.

Comment: I used the search function for you. See: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57713/bitcoin-cash-accidentally-sent-to-bitcoin-address-can-i-get-them-back/57714#57714

Comment: Still its not working for me :( As my wallet is bitpay. Wrote to bitpay support also. don't know why its not working. :(

Comment: Just got recovered. Found an article from bitpay themselves to recover bch from btc. https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005019583-How-Can-I-Recover-Bitcoin-Cash-BCH-from-My-Wallet-