# Can anyone intersept & redirect?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

Be kind! It was my first time!
Is there anyone out there that can intercept this transaction? Or redirect it to just return to the wallet it came from? It was my first transaction and I sent BCH to BTC. Expensive lesson!

1edfdf8e76e8e46fe5c1034ee129efd92b4b5d8f15004ae5acf1b961a176a809

Comment: It's a p2pkh address, so if you have the private key, you can just import it into a BCH wallet and send it out again.

Comment: Raghav Sood I do not know how to get a private key, it is my cash app wallet that I had attempted to send the BCH to. Is there a way?

Comment: Unfortunately Cash App holds the private keys and they seem unable to help. Someone else with the same problem's thread: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5218554.0

Comment: The only thing you can/should try to is e-mail the Cash App support and explain that you send BCH to their BTC address.

Comment: It has been confirmed 122 times now. What does that mean?

Comment: Also, one thing I'm unable to understand is: if BCH cannot be deposited into a BTC wallet, and their are 2 separate blockchains, why would I have to have the receiver wallet (BTC wallet) solve this? Wouldn't BCH still have full control if it's unable to deposit into the BTC wallet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitcoin Cash accidentally sent to Bitcoin address. Can I get them back?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57713/bitcoin-cash-accidentally-sent-to-bitcoin-address-can-i-get-them-back). Note that your BCH wallet sent BCH to an address you got from a BTC wallet but that address is just a number that, in some cases, is equally valid as a BCH address. The BCH and BTC networks are completely separate. In either network you can send money to an address that doesn't exist - but you can often create that address if you know a compatible private key.

Answer (score -1):

Your only hope would be getting that private key for your bitcoin address! Once you get that then import it into bitcoin cash wallet. You should be able to see your money and send it accordingly