# I sent some Bitcoin to a Bitcoincash adress on Trezor

Tags: bitcoin-cash, trezor

I sent some Bitcoin to a Bitcoincash adress on Trezor and it doesn't show on my Bitcoin in Trezor, how can I get them back ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would happen if you send Bitcoin (BTC) to a Bitcoin Cash (BCC) address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bcc-address)

Comment: I've voted leave open, because the related question explains the phenomenon in general whereas this question asks how to recover after the phenomenon on a specific device.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your Trezor firmware. Follow the steps here: https://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/updatingfirmware.html

After it, your problem should be solved. If not, try these steps: https://blog.trezor.io/claim-bcash-bitcoin-cash-bch-bcc-trezor-wallet-f0a810d5864a