# How can I recover BCH sent to a Trezor BTC address?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, wallet-recovery, trezor, breadwallet

I accidentally sent my BCH from Breadwallet to a BTC address from my Trezor wallet. Is there any way to retrieve that back to my BCH wallet? The BTC wallet I sent the money to is mine, so I own the keys but the address starts with 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would happen if you send Bitcoin (BTC) to a Bitcoin Cash (BCC) address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bcc-address)

Comment: @asterisk: I voted "leave open" because this question is in the other direction (BTC -> BCH vs BCH -> BTC). While related, there is a significant difference here, potentially the Bitcoin address is in the segwit format which is not supported on BCH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the steps from "How to claim your Bitcoin Cash (Bcash)" by Trezor Blog should do the trick.

https://blog.trezor.io/claim-bcash-bitcoin-cash-bch-bcc-trezor-wallet-f0a810d5864a

Steps:

1) Make sure Trezor uses latest firmware

2) Connect your Trezor

3) Go to [Coin splitting tool](https://trezor.io/claim-bch)

Comment: Note that if you have upgraded your Trezor to use SegWit addresses for Bitcoin already, you'll probably have difficulties recovering your BCH.

Comment: Yeah the trezor is updated with SegWit addresses so the money we sent to a new wallet. 

Trezor support said it's not possible to recover until BCH supports segwit.

is this valid?

Comment: @user14356 Yes, there's nothing you can try, unfortunately.

Comment: yeap the sucks. actually sucks that the guy who developed breadwallet didn't add that check there. easy to implement :)

Comment: @user14356 You can suggest a feature to breadwallet developers on https://github.com/voisine/breadwallet/issues/new (You need a GitHub account)

Comment: @user14356: Unfortunately, that's not correct. Segwit addresses look just like any other P2SH addresses, so it's not possible to check as a sender whether you're sending to P2SH-wrapped segwit address or other P2SH address.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Bitcoin address was already in the segwit format, you're in trouble. BCH does not support segwit, so it is difficult to build a BCH transaction to spend them and such a transaction would not be safe to broadcast to the BCH network— as on the BCH network it would be non-standard and could be doublespend with an "anyone can spend".

As far as I can tell, your only option would be to find a trustworthy miner whom you give the transaction **directly** that will include this non-standard anyone-can-spend transaction that sends the money to you, and doesn't just take the money for themselves. Also, you have to hope that no other miner replaces the block with another where they steal the money for themselves.

Since I'm not involved in the BCH community, I don't know whether there is any miner providing such a service at this time.

Comment: yeah i'm stuck so far :)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Unfortunately, I am no more involved in BCH than back when I wrote this answer and thus unable to provide further insight. Have you seen [Muscaria's answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/68129/5406)?

Answer (score 0):

[Ledger gives a guidance](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003836734-How-to-recover-BCH-sent-on-a-BTC-address-) on how to recover BCH sent to SegWit BTC address:

*If you sent BCH to a BTC Segwit address
Your BCH are stuck as Bitcoin Cash doesn't support Segwit. However you can use [this tool](https://bch.btc.com/docs/help/bch_segwit_recovery) to recover them.*