# Transfer incomplete and unspent

Tags: transactions

Im hoping i could get some assistance, im a newbie to cryptocurrency but will try my best to outline my Query,

I have transferred 0.06685156 BTC (incl. fees) from my Coinjar cash account to my Exodus Bitcoin cash Wallet 1HL3xwinsGfnNmTPsMrtzGgL3fud9pWDv1 on the 15th of November 2017.

It has now been 6 days and the funds have not yet come up on my Exodus Account.

I have checked on the blockchain but dont really understand what im looking for, i note this is showing up as  unspent, how can i fast track this particular transaction or what other options do i have.

Im happy to transfer a reasonable fee in BTC if someone can either clear this on my behalf  or provide a step by step guide for me to do it.

Transaction ID:
2d88911d1823c32ecd4dc951f87a830b680118f5b50c77fbb9b60fd02d22b83e

many thanks in advance

Comment: So you've sent a transaction from a Bitcoin address to a Bitcoin **Cash** address?  See this:  https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bcc-address

Answer (score 1):

I checked your tx on blockchain.info and the transaction is there. If you are 100% correct that the receiving Exodus address is correct then the transfer went through.

First recommendation I have is to try and manually refresh you Exodus account. Follow the steps in the link below and let me know if this solves the problem.

http://support.exodus.io/article/76-my-wallet-balance-is-not-correct

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your reply i can confirm that i have still not received the funds into my exodus account, not sure what else i can do, on the blockchain its showing up as unspent.

Comment: okay, i did some research on the Exodus knowledge base... they have a page specifically related to retrieving coins where BTC/BCH has been sent to the wrong address. try taking a look here and following the steps, and hopefully it helps you out... http://support.exodus.io/article/156-ive-sent-bitcoin-cash-to-my-bitcoin-address

Comment: AR71 you are the best.............., I followed your link and went through the steps on the link you provided and it actually worked, I really appreciate you taking your time to look into this. As i mentioned in my earlier post i am happy to transfer some BTC for the advise and steps in recovering my transfer, please send your details so i can make this happen, again much appreciated

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it worked out for you. No payment required. I'm just trying to pass it along. I crashed a Monero wallet in September and someone on Stack Exchange took time to help me. A lot of stuff in crypto isn't intuitive, so it's good if we can all help each other out. 