# Sent Bitcoin cash to Bitcoin wallet

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I made transfer by accident from my bitcash to my bitcoin address instead of bitcash to bitcash, and it's up in the cloud but I cannot claim it. I sent bitcash coins from CEX.IO wallet to my bitcoin account in Trezor.

The transaction went thru and now it's in a cloud on my account but because my account is bitcoin its not possible to get bitcash.

Does anyone know how I can release the money?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would happen if you send Bitcoin (BTC) to a Bitcoin Cash (BCC) address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bcc-address)

Comment: What it the first symbol of destination address? Is it "1" or "3"?

Comment: @MaxVernon: Nope, it's the other way around, and since BTC has since activated segwit, there's a significant difference.