# Bitcoin to Bitcoin Cash on Trezor

Tags: trezor, cross-chain-recovery

Just sent bitcoin to my Bitcoin Cash Wallet on Trezor. How can I retrieve it? 12-06-2016

Comment: Did you send BTC or BCH to  your Trezor?

Comment: BTC is what I sent to my Trezor

Comment: https://trezor.io/recover-coins/ <- does that help?

Comment: CORRECTION! It DID WORK thanks a million Slim - you're the best!

Comment: @slim: Please don't answer questions in the comment, rather write an answer post. Anybody else: Feel free to steal the "answer comment" and write an answer for easy reputation. ;)

Comment: My bad @Murch, I've put that comment in as an answer. I honestly didn't know if that was what he needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this website to recover your coinage: trezor.io/recover-coins

Comment: Would you please post an answer on our "canonical" BTC->BCH question, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bcc-address?  It will be much more visible to people.  It would be great if you can outline the steps required, rather than just giving a link which may eventually become invalid.