# How to return BCH with address BTC

Tags: transactions, wallet

The COPAY app I have 2 wallet,BTC and BCH. I transferred Cash to Bitcoin address BITCOIN, money stuck so BTC WALLET does not accept BCH how to get the money back or transfer them to BCH WALLET

Answer (score 0):

hopefully [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bch-aka-bcc-add) answer helps you.

Specifically,

> There is nothing which distinguishes a BCC address from a BTC address; they are both the same format and refer the the same keys, thus a BCC address is a BTC address and vice versa. This means that if someone sends BTC to an address that you created with a BCC wallet, **the person who owns that BCC wallet would receive BTC. It won't appear in his BCC wallet, but if he has the same private keys on a BTC wallet, he would receive the coins there and be able to spend it.**

Emphasis mine. Hopefully you have the private key!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and you can still tell when creating a wallet was a combination of 12 words-mnemonica,this is the private key for this application?